# Dropdown menu items lines doesn't start smoothly from the same position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how can I make that the list item lines of the dropdown menu should start from the left side smoothly?

As you can probably see that the icon is pushing the text to the right, how can I prevent this from happening?

And as you can see this is what I've got right now.

[image: Ay]

The three elements are not starting smoothly from the right, you can see some difference looking at the whole three elements.

This is my code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle cpm_lang" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/921/921701.png" data-src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/921/921701.png" srcset="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/921/921701.png 4x" alt="Ninja" title="Ninja" width="20" height="20" class="lzy lazyload--done">
   </a>
   <form class="dropdown-menu" style="background: #214971;" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header text-center text-light">{% if request.session.language == 'lt' %}Sveiki,{% elif request.session.language == 'en' %}Hey,{% elif request.session.language == 'rus' %}Привет,{%endif%} <span id="accountMenuHeader" style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;font-size: 18px;">{{request.user.first_name}}</span> &#128075;</h6>
      <div class="dropdown-divider" style="border: 0.1px solid #23394e !important;"></div>
      <h6 class="dropdown-header text-light text-left">{% if request.session.language == 'lt' %}Jūsų Sąskaita: {% elif request.session.language == 'en' %}Your bill: {%elif request.session.language == 'rus' %}Ваш счет: {%endif%}<a href="#" class="text-success" style="text-decoration: none;">&euro; 25.00</a></h6>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4" href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle text-left"></i> &nbsp; {% if request.session.language == 'lt' %}Užsakymai {% elif request.session.language == 'en' %}Orders {%elif request.session.language == 'rus' %}заказы{%endif%}</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-cog text-left"></i> &nbsp; {% if request.session.language == 'lt' %}Paskyros nustatymai {% elif request.session.language == 'en' %}Account settings {%elif request.session.language == 'rus' %}Настройки учетной {%endif%}</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-danger pl-4" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt text-left"></i> &nbsp; {% if request.session.language == 'lt' %}Atsijungti {% elif request.session.language == 'en' %}Logout {%elif request.session.language == 'rus' %}Отключить{%endif%}</a>
   </form>
</li>
```

- Note: This dropdown menu is made with bootstrap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `pl-4` bootstrap in-build class to each of the elements in the list.